# php cannot get value from html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have questions that why my html file cannot connect with php file.

But I am sure that after I click the submit button, value of `<input type="hidden" id="t1_response" name="t1_response" value="">` can be given.

However, url doesn't change to php form(like tocsv.php?t1_response=...).

And php gives me an notice :

Notice: Undefined index: t1_response in C:\xampp\htdocs\colors\tocsv.php on line 2

How can I fix it?

```
<script>
...
function pressSubmit() {
    $('#startTrial').hide();

    for (var i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
        rt = rt + parseFloat(document.getElementById("t"+i+"_rt").value);
    };
    if (document.getElementById("t1_response").value === "diff") {acc=acc+1};
    if (document.getElementById("t2_response").value === "diff") {acc=acc+1};
    if (document.getElementById("t3_response").value === "same") {acc=acc+1};


    document.write("<div>The average react time: " + rt/3 +" ms</div>");
    document.write("<div>Acc Rate:" + acc/3*100+"%</div>");


}

</script>

<style>
...
</style>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Remember the colors</h3>


Press 's' if the two displays are the same. Press 'd' if a color changed (different).<br>

<form action="tocsv.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="t1_response" name="t1_response" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="t1_rt" name="t1_rt" value="">

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" onclick="javascript:pressSubmit()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

pressSubmit() contains calculating average number and document.write() to display the value to user.

tocsv.php

```
<?php 
echo $_GET["t1_response"];
?>
```

Comment: What does `pressSubmit()` do?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `javascript:` in `onclick`. That's only needed when you put JavaScript in place of a URL, e.g. in `href`.

Comment: ```pressSubmit()``` is to calculate the average of react time and accuracy.
And I write ```document.getElementById("t1_response").value.....``` inside.

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what's being submitted.

Comment: regarding the path, it looks incorrect. For a start there should be 2 slashes after the directory letter. Also remember php runs server-side : have you tested it using a server space?

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes, I have tried other demo.html file in the same file and the demo works.

Comment: @nekokao the one you ran on the server doesn't have a c file path though does it? Check the file path again. Right click on the file you're targeting and copy the file path from the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problems.

Thanks everyone's help.

Here, in `pressSubmit()`, I wrote `doucument.write(...)`, which make the page to be overwritten. Thus, it came out to be unable to get the value and I have no idea why so.

Thus, I use `alert` to avoid to overwrite the page. And everything works.

Thanks everyone's help again!

---

.

Answer (score 0):

Error code is clear: you have to define the var t1_response in your php file.
I bet you write:

```
t1_response = $_POST['t1_response ']
```

but you need:

```
$t1_response = $_POST['t1_response ']
```

The html file you post here is ok.